# Magento, database dump

Tags: docker, magento, bitnami

I am trying to get db dump by command

```
docker exec container-name sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p""' > db-backups/some-dump-name.sql
```

and I am getting

```
Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitn
ami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)" when trying to connect
```

Magento runs on [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/magento/). Any ideas what could be wrong? I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You also need to set the hostname of the database when backing up the databases. The Magento container doesn't include a database server, it uses an external one.

You probably specified that using the `MARIADB_HOST` env variable. If you used the [docker-compose.yml file](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-magento/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) we provide, that hostname is `mariadb`.

```
exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -h HOSTNAME -p""
```

Comment: Thank you, I got dump file. But strangely, dump file has no tables info (database bitnami_magento). Although Magento is installed and working. Any clue?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I looked again, my database is somehow empty.